# Custom CXF Conduit

Tags: apache, cxf, cxf-client

I want to custom a CXF Conduit in my application, but i don't know how to implement it and add it in client code.

I want to implement it as custom destination that i have done as follows:

Step1: i create a MyDestinationFactory class

```
class MyDestinationFactory extends AbstractTransportFactory implements DestinationFactory {

....
}
```

Step 2: i add this Destination in the server code:

```
JaxWsServerFactoryBean serverFactory;
MyDestinationFactory destFac = new MyDestinationFactory();
serverFactory.setDestinationFactory(destFac);
```

It works with the custom destination.

=> How to customize a CXF Conduit ? I read here http://cxf.apache.org/docs/custom-transport.html but i don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Bus bus = BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus();


    MyTransportFactory customTransport = new MyTransportFactory();
    ConduitInitiatorManager extension = bus.getExtension(ConduitInitiatorManager.class);
    extension.registerConduitInitiator(MyTransportFactory.TRANSPORT_ID, customTransport);
```